# How to start a named background process when using bash?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I have a script that looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

tsx watch services/$1/src/index.ts
```

This will start `tsc` for the given service:

```
script/start_service some-service
```

If I add `&` the end it gets executed as a job:

```
script/start_service some-service &
```

but I still get some output. Then if I redirect (all) its output to `/dev/null`:

```
 script/start_service some-service > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

it starts the service properly in the background, but I can't look it up after my script returns.

What I'm trying to figure out is how to add a name (or some other unique identifier) to the job I start so that I can look it up later from another script (and possibly terminate it if necessary).

Note that [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/153900/how-can-i-start-a-process-with-a-different-name) question is related, but I can't figure out how to apply the answer to my use case. The answer:

```
bash -c "exec -a MyUniqueProcessName <command> &"
```

doesn't work for me. No matter what I do I don't get a process with the name I passed.

**Note that** the reason why I don't just assign the `pid` to a variable is that my script terminates and whenever the user calls my script again it needs to check which services are running at the moment and it doesn't have access to the ephemeral local variables that would have been created by the previous execution of the script.

Comment: Try using `screen` to start the script in the background.

Comment: Possibly related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/622124/how-to-execute-an-script-as-daemon-with-nohup/622143#622143

Comment: @Kusalananda not related, as I know in advance the names of these services and I want to "tag" the background process with this name. I have no access to the pid (or any other data) after my script returns.

Comment: @user68186 how does `screen` work?

Comment: @AdamArold But according to the code in your question, you could just use `somescript some arguments >/dev/null 2>&1 & pid_mything1=$!` and you would have the PID of this particular script in `$pid_mything1` to use later (passing it around in a script or even handing it to another script as an argument).  You could do the same for any number of background tasks.  You could even append the value of `$!` in an array with `myscript & pids+=( $! )`.  It is not clear from your question why you need to "tag" the processes in any special way.  See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30370

Comment: This is just a small extract from the code I have. I have a script that displays a list of all the services  (using whiptail checkboxes), and the user can toggle which services to have running. This script terminates leaving all the variables behind until the user calls the script again (so `pids` will be gone by then if I understand correctly)

Comment: @AdamArold This is definitely not clear from the question.

Comment: @AdamArold [How to use screen command?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/904373/how-to-use-screen-command) Also see [Is there any user friendly alternative to screen?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/449597/is-there-any-user-friendly-alternative-to-screen)

Comment: @Kusalananda I updated my question.